# Restore deleted mysql data

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to restore the mysql data which deleted by " delete from table " ?
I found there is a software "ApexSQL", anyone used it before? Is it possible to restore?
Or any other method that can be restore. I am not drop table .

http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx?_kk=log%20explorer

Comment: Asking the obvious, but Do you have backups?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924823/how-to-recover-just-deleted-rows-in-mysql , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173049/recovery-after-wrong-mysql-update-query ,

Comment: It is possible to restore deleted data. Are you using MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: I am a newbie i dont know what is MyISAM , lnnoDB

Comment: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-engines-myisam-vs-innodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to recover deleted data (deleted with DELETE statement). For InnoDB you can use open source tool by Percona mentioned in their [blog post](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/02/20/how-to-recover-deleted-rows-from-an-innodb-tablespace/). For MyISAM tables you can use ApexSQL or use this [tool](http://www.diskinternals.com/mysql-recovery/).